# Implement Google translate API in Python for translation of text from French to English for large dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, google-translate, language-translation, google-translation-api

I want to translate an excel with more than 10000 rows of french text into english using google translate API for Python.
I am able to do so using the code, but it allows translation till a certain limit. But, I want to use it for entire the dataset for official purpose.

```
import pandas as pd
import googletrans
from googletrans import Translator

df = pd.read_excel('frenchtext.xlsx')
translator = Translator()

def toenglish(x):
    print(x)
    result = translator.translate(x, dest='en')
    return result.text

df['Eng-text']= list(map(toenglish, df['Fr-text']))
```

How can I integrate the Python google translate API key for translation of entire dataset.

Comment: the translate API isn't free it comes at a [cost](https://cloud.google.com/translate/pricing)

Comment: As it is for official use, I can use the paid version.

Comment: then you'll need to use the official API this one isn't official nor is it stable, according to it's creator. have a look @ this : https://googleapis.dev/python/translation/latest/index.html